# Uniqueness of solution to the wave equation

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, wave-equation

Consider the Cauchy problem to the free wave equation

$\begin{align}
u_{tt}-\Delta u=0,\newline
u(0,x)=\phi(x), \newline
u_t(0,x)=\psi(x)
\end{align} \quad \text{with }  t \geq 0, x \in \mathbb{R}^n$

where $\phi, \, \psi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. Using Fourier transform, I found a solution to this problem in terms of Fourier multipliers.
How can I show that this solution is unique?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can find all the answers [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/360886/uniqueness-of-solution-of-the-wave-equation).

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much. So the uniqueness is justified by the properties of isomorphism of the Fourier transform and the uniqueness of solution to the ODE that results when I apply the transformation. That's it?